# simple, intuitive barrier option derivation

Tags: options

Is there a simple integral that gives barrier option prices without having to deal with messy, hard PDEs and change of variables

I understand there is a reflection principle such that the simulation stock prices bounces off the reflection at the barrier $b$

Taking the derivative with respect to $x$ and plugging in $b$ it's equal to zero, so the PDF should be something like this

$(e^{-((x-u)/a)^2/2}+e^{-((x+u-2b)/a)^2/2)})/(2\pi)^{1/2}$

and with the help of wolfram alpha I got this:

I don't know how to get this part: $(\frac{p}{b})^{a}$ Every barrier option pricing formula has this distinctive feature, but i don't know how you get that from $e^{a^2t+2b}$

Here's the integral

https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/9/d/8/9d80d384d06e1e2068c1463e08fe8a61.png

Comment: The link appears broken. Can you please update it?

Comment: updated broken link

Comment: The formula is not long, you may add to the question itslef instead of a link so that people are easy to follow. In addition, you may need to define all the notations you have used, for example, what are $p$, $p_s$, $p_1$, $p_b$, $a$, and $u$ etc. I believe many people can answer your question if the notations are clear.

Answer (score 4):

Try this paper by Rolf Poulsen : http://colloquium.mathfinance.de/abstracts/poulsen.pdf.  He derives barrier option prices in the Black-Scholes model using only reflection and Girsanov's Theorem, and then discusses extensions.

Comment: This is close to a link only answer, can you expound a bit?

Answer (score 1):

an up and out call involves an absorbing barrier. There is no pricing formula with a reflective barrier.

Comment: You may add this to your question above, instead of an answer. As I have commented above, the link in your question appears broken.